# Quelle est la différence entre « à » et « en » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, à

Quelle est la différence entre  « à »  et  « en » ?

Par exemple, doit-on dire : « diviser une table en des cases » ou « diviser une table à des cases » ?

Quand doit-on utiliser « à » et « en » ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Phrase correcte:**

> diviser une table en des cases

Plus joli: on peut omettre *des*:

> diviser une table en cases

La forme diviser *une table à des cases* est **incorrecte**, et ne veut rien dire.

**à et en sont deux prépositions. Utilisées seules, elles ont un sens distinct**:

**à** : situation géographique localisée à un emplacement: *Je suis à Paris, à la campagne.*

**en** : situation géographique localisée à l'intérieur d'un lieu, ou comme moyen (à l'intérieur): *Je suis en ville, je me déplace en métro.*

**Mais il y a plein de nuances**: *en voiture* (dedans), *à vélo* (sur).

**à a d'autres d'emplois**, dont un très fréquent est d'introduire un COI: je parle à Jean, Je donne cette pomme à ma fille.

**en peut aussi introduire une forme de type gérondif** (participe présent):

> en chantant, en parlant, ...

**à et en sont également utilisées avec des verbes** (à très souvent), pour former des constructions propres à chaque verbe:

> diviser / couper / découper en morceaux.
>
> parler à, donner à, répondre à,